ESTA re entry to USA
There are lots of posts on this for 90 day stays, but I want a much shorter stay.
My intention is to fly from  London to Miami, stay there 3 days, on 4th day fly to Cartagena, Colombia stay there for 5 days. Then fly back to USA, possibly Miami or some other city, staying there for 3 days before going back to London.
Am I allowed to go back to USA on an ESTA?
Or should I look at flying to a different country on the way back such as Costa Rica?
I don’t really want border problems. In addition I am a solo traveler so that always puts me in a higher risk category.

Thank you to everyone who answered. That’s helpful to know it should be fine. I wanted to avoid flying via Bogotá due to altitude.

I did various South American trips with transit in US with ESTA. It ass never a problem. (Note: US doesn't really consider "transit" a thing, so always with immigration, custom, security check)

I see nothing in your plan that would raise any concern. An ESTA is valid for two years and using it for multiple entries is perfectly fine, I do it all the time.
The reason people write so much about stays around 90 days (in the US or in neighboring countries) is that 90 days is the maximum length of stay authorized under the Visa Waiver Program. If you are getting close to it, the details of the rules, what counts as a separate stay, etc. begin to matter. Multiple 90-day stays are also more likely to raise concerns about the real intent of the trip.
But none of this matters for your trip, which is only 11 days in total, nowhere near a length of stay that could cause trouble.

Just adding to this very clear answer. It is very likely that you will be readmitted on the terms of the initial admission. Example: You are admitted on Oct 30 2024 and your I94 says you are admitted until Jan 28 2025. You stay until Nov 1 2024 and then leave to Colombia. You come back to the US on 6 Nov 2024, your admission will just fall under the previous one. Meaning you have to leave by maximum Jan 28 2025. Hope that's clear.

@Ozzy Given that OP is travelling to a country which is not part of the "Contiguous territory or adjacent islands", it should actually not be the case, a new I-94 should be issued for a full 90 days.

@jcaron: Either way, it is profoundly unlikely that CBP will have a problem with this itinerary (unless OP is on some sort of list, in which case they probably wouldn't have an ESTA in the first place).

@Kevin Oh definitely, no issue with the itinerary.
